# sqlite3_open: "unable to open database file"

Tags: c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I get "unable to open database file" when executing rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);  ??

```
sqlite3 *db; // sqlite3 db struct
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int rc;

// Open the test.db file
rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db); // <-- creates DB if not found ??

if( rc ){
    // failed
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sqlite3_open` returns an error if the database does not already exist. To create the database if it doesn't already exist, use `sqlite3_open_v2` with the `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`  and `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` flags (**both are required**):

```
rc = sqlite3_open_v2(/* DB Path */, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)

---

To find `/* DB PATH */`, you need to base the filename off of the documents directory:

```
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

You can use this convenience method to combine the documents path with the database name:

```
NSString *documents = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSString *dbPath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];

rc = sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you I had tried that and got "ERROR: Can't open database: out of memory" ??

Comment: Where is `test.db` located (or should be created)?

Comment: My understanding is if the file is not present, it will create it?

Comment: Yes, but you can only write to the documents directory, so the path needs to be based there.

Comment: How should I phrase it then in Cocoa-touch?

Comment: Thank you... Methodology is a big help... but I still get "out of memory" from sqlite3_errmsg?

Comment: What if you replace `NULL` with an empty string: `""`?

Comment: empty string "" yields same message: "out of memory"

Comment: What is the output when you `NSLog(dbPath)`?

Comment: /Users/XXXXX/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/XXXXXX/Documents/test.db

Comment: Okay, I missed the fact that *two* flags were needed. See my updated answer.

Comment: Things may have changed since 2012, I'm not sure, but at the moment the documentation states that `sqlite3_open()` does READWRITE and CREATE flags by default: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Comment: In my particular case there was a hardcoded `/sdcard/dbname.sqlite3` which may not exist in all devices (the path, that is; the db should be automatically created as @void.pointer pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define SQLITE_OK 0
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg=0;
if(sqlite3_open("demo.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, "select * from Users", callback, 0, &zErrMsg) == SQLITE_OK)
            msgbox1("success");
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
else
    msgbox1("failure");
```

here is the sample code which i use;