# How to use sqlite3 in a cocos2d-x project in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, sqlite, cocos2d-x

I download C/C++ interface for SQLite from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). And I get 4 source files `shell.c`, `sqlite3.c`, `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3ext.h`.

Now I add all these 4 files into my cocos2d-x project and use the following code for test:

```
#include "sqlite/sqlite3.h"

sqlite3 *pDB = NULL;
char * errMsg = NULL;
std::string sqlstr;
int result;

result = sqlite3_open("save.db", &pDB);
if( result != SQLITE_OK )
    CCLog( "failed，status_code:%d ，error_msg:%s\n" , result, errMsg );

sqlite3_close(pDB);
```

Then I run it. But it builds failed, the error is showing below:

> duplicate symbol _main in:
>
> /Users/tangyue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrossKaiser-bkepfijxelboxkchsxvcmpozrwlt/Build/Intermediates/CrossKaiser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CrossKaiser.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
>
> /Users/tangyue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CrossKaiser-bkepfijxelboxkchsxvcmpozrwlt/Build/Intermediates/CrossKaiser.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CrossKaiser.build/Objects-normal/i386/shell.o
>
> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I think there must be a `main` in these file, which occurs this error. And I find `main` method in the file `shell.c`. Because  I don't include this file in my test code, I remove it from the project.

Then I run it again. This time, it build success, but the value of `result` is **NOT** `SQLITE_OK`, it is 14(`SQLITE_CANTOPEN`), which means 'Unable to open the database file'.

Now what should I do to run the program correctly? What is the `shell.c` file used for, and is it wrong for me to remove it from project.

[**update**]

---

I solove it use the following code:

```
string dbPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWriteablePath();
dbPath.append("save.db");

CCLog("%s", dbPath.c_str());

result = sqlite3_open_v2(dbPath.c_str(), &pDB, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
```

instead of

```
result = sqlite3_open("save.db", &pDB);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove shell.c from your project. It is cli tool to work with sqlite databases. It define main() because it is executable.

Regarding second part of your question [sqlite3_open: "unable to open database file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250870/sqlite3-open-unable-to-open-database-file)

Comment: Thank for your help, and after my some work on finding correct file path, my problem is soloved.